# ng-repeat still displays removed items when used with ng-animate in angular 1.4.0-rc2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

When I tried to migrate my app to Angular 1.4.0-rc2 (release candidate), I hit into problem: when I load `ngAnimate` as dependency of my app, `ngRepeat` directive stops to remove deleted items from HTML DOM. Problem doesn't show up when I don't load `ngAnimate` or when I use Angular 1.3.x.

[Plunker app demonstrating problem](http://plnkr.co/edit/MEVvm5rzRqJYUMpwtgcK)

Is this a bug in 1.4.0-rc2 or do I do something wrong? I looked at breaking changes of 1.4 but it didn't help me solve this problem.

Comment: That's odd - it also has something to do with the form. If you remove the ng-form or move it outside the ng-repeat the problem also goes away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My question finally was answered on angularjs discussion group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/ZSUB17o4jd0.

Here is the answer, all credit goes to Sander Elias.

Using multiple directives on a single element throws the animator off. I do understand why this happens, but in my opinion the animator should throw a warning/error in the console.
your problem is easily fixed tough:

```
<div ng-repeat="s in vm.wrapper.strings track by $index">
    <ng-form name="blahForm">
        <select ng-model="vm.wrapper.strings[$index]" ng-options="obj.value as obj.name for obj in vm.options" name="xxx" required>
            <option>Wybierz</option>
        </select>
    </ng-form>
</div>
```

put the ngForm in its own element, and it will work like you expect.